# How to make a web bot to check for updates

Tags: c#, wpf, web, bots

How can I make a program that checks for updates on this site or facebook, etc.

Comment: If you consider that SO is probably changing at the rate of hundreds of new entries, edits, etc., per hour (thousands ?), then I think a logical question to ask is : what do you have in mind for filtering the updates, or "targeting" specific topics. In other words : I think it would help you get more focused answers if you clearly describe exactly what type of material you want to check for updates on. Checking for all new/edited/commented-on posts with the tag "c#" is one thing; checking on changes in your own user status is another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to create HTTP requests.

If you want a more specific answer please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or implement the HTTP protocol directly in your application. Can you be more specific as to what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Say your app saves the  string for any given website **today**. You would use the WebClient class to .DownloadData(). Correct?

Then say, next week you want to see if the  tag has changed, .DownloadData() again and compare with the string you saved last week. If it is different, save the string (overwriting the previous value) and you're done.

This is just a basic outline on the steps necesary for something like this. At least, this is how I would do it. :)

Check out the WebClient class and specifically the DownloadData method. Works like a charm. :)

*Note that when using DownloadData your GUI will freeze. If you want to avoid this, you must use DownloadDataASync() method.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow.com provides RSS feeds. The simplest solution is download [Argotic](http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic), an RSS framework for .NET/C#, and use this with your application to get the latest feeds.

Point Argotic at:

- https://stackoverflow.com/feeds

For Facebook you could use the [Facebook toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit).